# hibernate jpa update two field on persisit and read from one only

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

one quick question for java hibernate/jpa users.

I have two tables(entities) A and B with relations as A has many B (one to many). Entity A has Set of values B in java.

Due to read performance issue i want to implement master-details denormalization, so i want to store raw Set object (maybe serialized) directly in entity A (because many to one relation cost me to much cpu time because of read by jpa (update is not an issue)).

The problem is, can i achieve something like that getBs always returns me denormalized object (so its fast) and addB adds new B to Set and updates denormalized object with new raw data that is prepared for faster read?

its oracle db.

entity example:

```
class A {
    Long id,
    String name;
    Set<B> arrayOfBs;
    byte[] denormalizedArrayOfB;

    getArrayOfBs() {
        return (Set<B>) denormalizedArrayOfB;
    }

    addArrayOfBs(B b) {
        //persist b
        // update and persist denormalizedArray with new b
    }
    //getters and setters...
}

class B {
    Long id;
    A reference;
    String x;
    String y;
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's complicated. There are better approaches to your problem:

1. You can simply replace the one-to-many association with a DAO query. So whenever you fetch the parent entities you won't be able to get the children collection (maybe they are way too many). But when you want to get a parent's children, you simply run a DAO query, which is also easier to filter.
2. You leave the children collection, but you use an in-memory cache to save the fully initialized object graph. This might sounds like a natural choice, but most likely you're going to [trade consistency for performance](http://vladmihalcea.com/caching-best-practices/).

Comment: 1. Ok, but its still problem with storing two attributes, normalized and denormalized one.
2. I dont want to lose consistency

Comment: And the duplicated denormalized data doesn't mean a break in consistency?

Comment: Ok, maybe i could use that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771015/setting-a-bean-value-column-automatically-before-persisting-in-hibernate